# Interchanging finite limit and infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm interested in the behaviour of
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(x,n,\varepsilon).$$
Since we are taking a finite limit. Will it necessarily be true that
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(x,n,\varepsilon)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} f(x,n,\varepsilon)$$
or is further justification required with the dominated/monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: Interchanging any limit operation with a series (which is another limit operation) requires justification. It doesn’t matter if you’re taking $\epsilon\to 0$ or $\epsilon\to\infty$ or $\epsilon\to a$ for some $a\in [-\infty]$ or $a\in\Bbb{C}$ or anything else.

Comment: The general condition justifying the exchange of two limits is that the double limit converges. In your case, This is the condition that there exists $L$ such that for all $\eta > 0$, there exist $\delta > 0, M \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $\varepsilon, N$, if $|\varepsilon - 0| < \delta$ and $N \ge M$, then $$\left|\left(\sum_{n=0}^Nf(x,n,\varepsilon)\right) - L\right| < \eta$$Here, $L$ can depend on $x$. If the double limit exists, then you are justified in exchanging the order of the single limits. But there are cases when the single limits are exchangable without the double limit existing